# Unable to send an array to mongoDB by form-data using postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman, formidable

I am implementing an api right now to add products to the database, the product should contain an array field *tags*, which should keep a number of string values in it. In postman I am posting through form-data as I am using formidable in my nodejs for picture upload.
mongoose schema example:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

Title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 32,
},
Description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 500,
},
tags: [{
    type: String
}],
Quantity: {
type: Number,
required:true,
},
Price: {
type: Number,
required: true,
},
Picture: {
    data: Buffer,
    pictureType: String,
} }, {timestamps: true} );
module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);
```

**The code for sending the product:**

```
const formidable = require("formidable");
const fileSystem = require("fs");
const Product = require("../models/product")
exports.productController = (req, res)=> {                           

const formidableMethod = new formidable.IncomingForm();

formidableMethod.keepExtensions = true,

formidableMethod.parse(req, (err, fields, files)=> {
    if (err){
        return res.status(400).json({error: "Error during uploading img"})
    } 
    const productSet = new Product(fields); 
    if (files.image){
        productSet.Picture.data = fileSystem.readFileSync(files.Picture.path);
        productSet.Picture.pictureType = files.Picture.type;
    }
    productSet.save((err, output)=>{
        if (err){
            return res.status(400).json({error: "Error saving the product", })
        }
      res.json(output);  
    } )
});
```

In postman, I am using form-data to post the product. I have tried different ways for the "tags" array.
I have tried several fields *tags* in the body, with different values. tags[0], tags[1] and other ways.
I tried changing the array format in the schema in different ways, with type: Array or simply tags:[String]. The best thing I've got right now is that postman will add my request into the first element of the array, ignoring all of the other ones.
I have suspected it might be due to me using formidable, I have tried setting the formidable options ( multiples to true ) but also with no luck. I am not sure if my problem is with postman, the schema or formidable.
Right now postman returns to me, from a form-data request with 3 fields (tags) in the key of the body is:

```
{
    "tags": [
        "value 3"
    ],
    "_id": "5eca55570587f91638280255",
    "Title": "Adding product test",
    "Description": "Description test",
    "Quantity": 10,
    "Price": 49,
}
```

Shows only value 3, ignoring the value 1 and value 2. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you console req.body before formidable parse, and confirm that it is bcoz of postman

Comment: The console log shows {} . Now I am even more confused.

Comment: Can you confirm whether it works when you set Content-Type to JSON?

Comment: I have tried setting the content type to application/json in postman. No luck. Im not sure why the body is undefined though. I do have app.use(bodyParser.json()); in my main index.js file along with other middleware